# Is there any way to create ip-independent http session?

Tags: http, session, authentication

I have seen some sites, where your authentication does note expire after your ip changes. How to create such session, and how safe is it?

Comment: "HTTP sessions" don't exist; you just mean *sessions*, as in *session cookies*? They're easy to do, by default they don't depend on the IP at all.

Comment: So, how does session validate then? by some hardware information?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how does session validate then? by some hardware information?

The fact that you have a session cookie is the validation.

Sessions work by creating a server-side resource with a ***random id***. For example, a random id is created, `iuwehrc3948hg3w09x4h`, and an entry in a database is saved with it. That random id is sent as a cookie to the browser. The browser returns this cookie with every request, the server looks up the database entry with this id and gets the associated session data.

The "validation" is that the browser possesses a valid session id. The browser can only know this id if it was given to it by the server previously. Because the id is entirely random, it should practically be unguessable by any 3rd party.

Having said this, *cookie hijacking* is a concern, in which a 3rd party outright steals a valid session cookie (e.g. through a shared network, malware installed on the victim's machine etc.). In this case recording the IP address of the client in the session and validating it as well can help mitigate problems; but as you note, it also means that sessions have an extremely limited life span. The most practical solution to avoid session hijacking is to use HTTPS throughout.